# Repurposing state variable on upgrade

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I happen to be removing a uint and adding a uint in the same upgrade. Is there any reason for me not to simply change the name of the uint and start using it for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* be fine, however you need to take care while doing it. There are several ways to "shoot yourself in the foot" doing this by either messing up the storage slot it points to or just forgetting to remove code that altered the old variable. It would be difficult to say it's entirely safe without going through all the code, both pre-upgrade and post-upgrade